# How can I completely wipe my hard drive along with Ubuntu so that I can boot off of a fresh OS without anything on the hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I can't find any other questions that have helped, all I want to do is get rid of EVERYTHING on the hard drive including Ubuntu and I can't figure out how. Does anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to. When you install the new OS, you should always have an option to use whole disk or do manual partitioning.

But if you want to do it anyway, boot your pc up on Ubuntu from a USB stick, use gparted (gui) or parted (cmdline) to delete partitions of your harddisk.

Alternatively use, booted from USB, to wipe all data and partitions:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=4096
```

You have to find what X is (propably a or b) by running 'fdisk -l' or similar.

Comment: Thanks Soren, I think that will work for Windows but I am trying to install ZorinOS which is a Linux OS. For some reason when I try to install it using USB it boots directly to Ubuntu

Comment: If it boots directly into Ububtu, it's propably because Boot order in bios dont have USB before Harddisk. At boot, see what key your bios uses to enter boot options. Propably F11 or something.